# Overstay in uk for 18 months and want to visit Australia

Tags: australia

I overstayed in uk on a student visa for about 18 months but tried for an extension when my visa expired and was rejected as I couldn't pay my uni fee. I'm married now and he wants to take me on a tourist visa to Australia.i have a new passport with my spouses name and surname. I voluntarily came back to India and have no exit stamp. Wht are my chances of Australia visit??

Comment: all the relevant dates are missing, marking as unclear

Comment: I've overstayed from Nov 2011 to Jan 4 2013. Now I've got a new passport with surname and spouses name added. Will my overstay effect my Australian visa ??

Comment: Those dates are in the UK's biometric window.  Are you aware that Australia requires biometric enrolment for visa applicants and that Australia is a signatory to the Five Eyes Treaty?  Reopen voted, 4 more required.

Comment: Thank u for ur response but r u saying tht I cannot make it to any of those 5 countries then?

Comment: No. I am saying that it seems you intend to rely upon a changed identity because your passport has different info.  I am minded to mark your question as a duplicate to this one http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67808/is-changing-your-passport-a-good-strategy-for-removing-a-negative-immigration-hi  would you agree?