# UK: Is a 10 year ban still valid after acquiring new citizenship?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, dual-nationality, visa-bans

I am an Indian national and was refused a UK visa in 2009 in NYC and given a 10 year ban, but now I'm a US citizen.

---

Would the ban still apply if I wanted to visit the UK?

Comment: A good way to get your ban extended is to enter the UK under a different identity while a ban is in effect.  It's covered in Paragraph 321 of the rules and I suggest reading it.

Comment: Are you asking whether they will know that it's still you?

Comment: Were your biometrics enrolled in the UK database? And do you still have the same name? Unless the answer is 'no' to both, the UK can definitely know it's you.

Comment: Curious, why were you banned and why can you not wait 18 months? As a British citizen, I would like to think that if you were banned from my country, it was for a good reason. A ban is far more serious than being turned away and the length would suggest that you have a very real reason to be kept out.

Comment: Oh, congrats on becoming a US citizen!

Comment: @JonathanReez they can probably match biometrics even if the name is completely different.  That's one reason for using biometrics.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/89995/4188

Answer (score 59):

The ban is not against your passport, it is against you the human being bearing the passport and hence regardless of whichever different nationalities you assume or acquire (barring somehow acquiring British or EU citizenship), the ban remains in effect.

If you decide you still want to visit the UK **after** your ban is over, make sure you get entry clearance to ensure a smoother (your landing is virtually guaranteed to be a bit rocky regardless of whether you get entry clearance or not because of the ban which is a serious black mark) landing process when you arrive in the UK although you are allowed visa free entry as a US citizen. Attempting to enter visa free can lead to much grief as happened to another [recently naturalized American](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87121/recently-naturalized-american-visiting-uk-previously-refused-should-i-apply-fo) UK visitor in a somewhat similar situation to yours.

Comment: happened to another.... you ;) Like Paul says, wait for your ban to end and apply for a visitors visa

Comment: Note that a ban is much more serious than simple refused entry. I'd say your chances of getting through without at least some additional disruption are only if they fail to notice you had the previous ban.

Comment: @CMaster the OP isn't banned from the UK as in he doesn't have a deportation order against him. He isn't banned from applying for a visa or showing up at a UK port either. However, his visa/entry will be refused until the 10 years are up.

Comment: "regardless of whatever different nationalities you assume or acquire" I realise this is a nitpick, but gaining British nationality would be an exception to this.

Comment: @Vality or marrying a British national, gaining EU nationality or marrying an EU national. Or if there are human rights considerations. Or if it's deemed to be in the public good.

Comment: The weird thing about this is that if you switch passports/identities your visa will not be valid in the new situation, but if you do the same while under a ban, the ban will still be in effect? Why can't they be consistent about it?

Comment: @Mehrdad: this is not true. If you carry both your old passport with visas together with the new one, the visas will be valid. There are some exception, but this is generally the case.

Comment: @QuoraFeans: The equivalent of that would be if the ban was also still valid if and only if you carried both passports. Clearly the ban is effect even if you don't have your old passport, so why isn't the visa?

Comment: @Mehrdad it is, which is why they let you use it when you provide adequate evidence. The difference is, it's up to you to prove you should be let in, but they don't leave it up to you to prove that you're banned ;)

Comment: @hobbs: I mean, sufficient proof of identity should be adequate evidence. Sure, maybe even more evidence than they originally need, to prevent fraud. But there's gotta be some amount that's sufficient. Yet they instead require you to have the physical sticker they gave you? I can literally think of no reason other than that they just don't feel like dealing with it.

Comment: @Mehrdad The world of visas etc. is in transition between two systems. It used to be totally paper orientated. It is heading towards being based on biometrics and databases. It will be a bit mixed up for at least the next decade.

Comment: @Mehrdad: the visa is valid, you just have to 'transfer' it. It's in your interest to prove that you have a visa. Regarding the ban, it's the other way round. It's not in the interest of the banned person to prove it, therefore, they have to check their db.