# UK visit visa ban after becoming an Australian national

Tags: australian-citizens, visa-bans

I've been banned from the UK for 10 years for not providing full information. Now I am an Australian citizen. Does this ban still exist? Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: Answered here: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92990/uk-is-a-10-year-ban-still-valid-after-acquiring-new-citizenship

Comment: @Molot - I would suggest that the distinction of Australia being a Commonwealth member state and the US not being makes this enough of a different question that it isn't a duplicate, even if it actually makes no difference in the answer: people may generally assume that it might.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, the ban still applies.

The ban applies to the person, not the citizenship.  Even though as an Australian Citizen you do not need a visa to visit the UK, you are still subject to the 10 year ban, and thus can not visit.

It is **possible** that if you were to attempt to visit the UK using your Australian passport you would be admitted on the grounds that they may not realize you were the same person that was banned, however even this is unlikely as you will still have the same name, date of birth, and place of birth (all of which are on your passport).  Even so, this would be illegal, and you would likely be subject to a further ban if you were caught.

You could certainly attempt to apply for a new visa for the UK. Given your new citizenship it is possible they may choose to overturn the ban, although I can't comment on how likely (or not) that would be.

Comment: There is no legal provision to overturn the ban

Comment: With the Home Office's "hostile environment" policy I think there is very little chance of being admitted.

Comment: @user Bans are not served on a whim to travellers. And the traveller would have been a given a reason with explanation for the ban. Home Office isn't hostile. The OP would have given them reasons to ban him(her).

Comment: @DumbCoder The OP was banned for false representations. Any application during the 10 year period (unless the OP can show he did not intend to deceive)for a visa or leave at a border point will fall to be refused under mandatory grounds for refusal. There is no discretion. And yes, the home office policies are hostile, discriminatory  and not transparent. However, since British citizens are not directly affected,nobody cares.

Comment: @greatone - `the home office policies are hostile, discriminatory and not transparent` That is an asinine generalization. Show me one country whose visa granting process is **transparent**, as you mention. It is expected for a visa applier to be careful and not falsify facts. There are ample steps provided to question UKVI's decision if you believe they are in fault. Try any of the European countries to question their decision, it should be an eye opener for you.

Comment: @DumbCoder I'm not comparing the UK's visa process to anybody else's. International borders are discriminatory and anti-liberal by nature. However, the UK's own written policies on immigration encourage discrimination based on nationality and religion. Independent reports from the UK government also highlight discrimination and a lack of transparency in the decision making process.

Comment: @DumbCoder The UK Home office has a [policy of being hostile to illegal immigrants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_Office_hostile_environment_policy) in the hope that they will choose to leave the UK. This includes, for example, requiring landlords and employers to check that tenants and employees are legally in the UK. The word "hostile" is their own description.