# foreigner reentering US after overstaying the visa

Tags: visas, usa, passports

I'm currently 3years banned for entering in US after overstaying my visa, is it possible to request a visa to come back with a different passport? Would that work?

Comment: Are you trying to reenter the USA fraudulently? You would be risking a permanent bar if you try doing so. Bad idea. In this day and age of terrorism and computers linked to databases with terabytes of data, those days of sneaking through are long gone.

Answer (score 7):

Unlikely to work. Your ban is against you and getting a new passport doesn't change who you are. Your name, date of birth and place of birth will still be the same.

Have a look at this similar situation [UK: Is a 10 year ban still valid after acquiring new citizenship?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92990/uk-is-a-10-year-ban-still-valid-after-acquiring-new-citizenship/92991#92991)