# Was refused in UK, should I replace my passport?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, denial-of-entry

My entry was refused in London. I was just visiting for 20 days from Italy where I'm visiting too. They sent me back to Italy. Now I would like to know if is better to get a new passport here before I travel again because that black X stamped in my passport is not a good sight.

After here I will go to Romania and then probably get a student visa for Italy.

Comment: What's you nationality? Why was entry in UK refused? Will you travel to the UK, again, or do you mean other countries will see that UK refused entry?

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56879/getting-refused-entry-and-removed-at-heathrow-x-in-passport/56889#56889

Comment: I was told when I was renewing my passport to keep my old one around (after it was "destroyed" by employee (each page stamped with "cancelled", chip destroyed and cut on edges)) and keep it with me in case it was requested on border or when applying for a visa. So far it wasn't requested, but I assume it might be if it had visas. (this is Turkey, fwiw)

Comment: What would you be trying to achieve by getting a new passport? You give the reason "that black X stamped in my passport is not a good sight" but I'm assuming you mean something more than that you literally don't like how it looks?

Comment: Strongly related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67808/is-changing-your-passport-a-good-strategy-for-removing-a-negative-immigration-hi

Comment: No I just had travelled for two years and everything in the law, never happened nothing like that, I’m business woman with blogger and other hobbies but I have all documents to proof myself and my true about everything. The situation about new passport is, every border around of the world will ask for what? And I really don’t like to review that situation to explain forever about something I don’t know what!! Brasil blacklist maybe I really don’t like that situation in my passport

Answer (score 50):

Regardless of the answers to the other requests for clarification

**Getting another passport will make exactly no difference to your situation.**

Countries like the UK have sophisticated means of tracking your previous attempts to enter, and will definitely pick up on your previous record. The big X is to make sure *you* know what has happened, not to tell future immigration officers to refuse you entry.

Comment: UK will know, as likely would most of the other EU countries. However, countries other than the UK could be less inclined to issue a visa (or even allowing visa-free entry) upon seeing the UK refusal stamp, and for them a fresh passport could be helpful, since they might not share data with the UK or not bother to check.

Comment: @dbkk “other EU countries” will not know, the UK does not participate in this part of the schengen information system.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the question. OP is asking whether or not it will affect his *subsequent* travel plans (i.e. to countries *other than* the UK).

Answer (score 32):

- As DJCalyworth wrote, the UK will know even if you get a new passport. They keep records.
- Other countries might be told by the UK, or not. Depends on how good their information interchange is. It would be a **really bad idea** to believe that requesting a new passport makes that information go away. When asked "have you ever been denied entry" e.g. by the US or Canada you should tell the truth.
- That refusal notice will only matter when some official looks through your passport without a more detailed application in his hands. In that case, you would have lost the positive impression of a travel history to Italy.

Comment: "you should tell the truth" - I would put that a lot stronger. "Lying will get you into deep trouble, even in cases where the truth was mostly harmless".

Comment: The refusal stamp will matter if any visa official is looking for a reason to deny a visa or entry. If you travel a lot, you occasionally come across such officials, even in countries with a generally permissive visa policy (e.g. Thailand).

Comment: @dbkk those officials will also have access to the same information as the border agents, and will thus know you were denied even if you have a new passport.

Comment: @jwenting Thai border officials will not know about a UK refusal in a previous passport. I doubt any other country beyond possibly Ireland would have that information shared (Ireland participates in immigration data sharing with the UK as part of the Common Travel Area)

Comment: I said the true all the time. They’ve got for themselves. I’m blogger but I have my own business and I have all documents, but they don’t bring one unique document for proof something, no account bank, no business agreement, and them I really don’t understand, how can we decide without see all my documents. I’m Italy my plan in London was 20days with a friends and back to Italy for Christmas 

Answer (score 6):

Where a new passport **won't help you**:

- Hiding your refusal from UK officials
- Hiding it from countries that share immigration data with the UK (the [Five Eyes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Eyes))
- Hiding it from countries that ask about previous immigration issues in other countries (e.g. Canada)
- Getting into the UK again without a change in your personal circumstances (more on that later)

Where a new passport would help:

- Entering or obtaining a visa from countries that don't share immigration data with the UK and don't ask about immigration complications in other countries (e.g. Thailand)
- Boarding a plane to the UK or Ireland (airlines might refuse you boarding if they see a refusal stamp)

Therefore my advice is to replace your passport, but only after your personal circumstances change:

- Have a clear explanation of why you're visiting the country and for how long
- Have your finances in good shape, which normally means having a stable job or other source of reliable income
- Have strong ties to your country of residency - studying in Italy could be a good start
- Obtain a visitor's visa to the UK, instead of relying on visa-free entry. It is a [recommended strategy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87121/recently-naturalized-american-visiting-the-uk-previously-denied-visa-apply-for) for people who have previously been refused entry to the UK, as it will clear your immigration history.